# What is the word for a matrix which has all zeroes in its last column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

In other words, every equation in the system of equations represented by the matrix equals zero. I know for a fact there's a specific name for this type of matrix, but I can't remember it. Any guesses?

Comment: For a matrix system $Ax=b$ to imply each and every row equation equals zero, then vector $b$ must be all zeroes, in which case the matrix system is called homogenenous; but it has nothing to do with the last column of $A$.

Comment: You might be thinking of the word "homogeneous"? A system of linear equations is homogeneous if each equation has $0$ on the right hand side. The augmented matrix of a homogeneous system has an augmented $0$ column. But, you don't hear of matrices in general being referred to as "homogeneous".